# Remove perviously added values from template created using Formset

Tags: python, django

I'm able to save values in database using Formset but when I tried to create one more form then perviously added values are getting showed in the template.

This is a strange issue but I want to know how to solve this issue.

Comment: You solve it by fixing your code.

Comment: Thank you for motivating me. I fixed the issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

For those don't know how to fix this issue then solution is here:

ModelFormset always sustains the old data. So instead of writing "modelformset_factory" inside the forms, write it in views.py like this:

```
smodelFormset=modelformset_factory(smodel,form= smodelForm,extra=1)
form=fmodelForm(request.POST or None)
formset=smodelFormset(request.POST or None, queryset=smodel.objects.none())

if request.method == 'POST':
   if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
      instance=form.save()
      forms=formset.save(commit=False)
      for f in forms:
       f.foreignkey=instance.id
       f.save()
```